# In javascript is -1 true or false?

Tags: javascript, boolean, truthiness

I can't figure out if -1 is true or false in javascript, when I use indexOf.

```
let a =  'abc'.indexOf('abc');  
let b =  'def'.indexOf('abc');   

console.log(a);     // 0
console.log(b);     // -1
console.log(!a);    // true
console.log(!b);    // false
```

Why are the last two lines giving true/false?

From what I understand only == allows for type converting, since (=== is strict)

Is (!a) and (!b) using (==) internally somewhere?

Comment: It is true (well, "truthy"). The only "falsey" number is zero. You need to test if it `== -1` is true.

Comment: It's neither, it's a number not a boolean, however it is *truthy*

Comment: It all started in c where 0 was false and everything else was true.  JavaScript tried to follow this, but it got messy quickly without strict type enforcement.

Answer (score 7):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that translates to true when evaluated in a Boolean context. **All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).** (emphasis mine)

This means `-1` is considered "truthy". You shouldn't be checking for "truthiness" *directly* on the value returned from `indexOf` anyway. `-1` has a *specific* meaning in that the element you are looking for does not exist in the array. So it would make more sense to explicitly test against `-1` using `===`. To anyone reading the code, the intent is also much clearer than coercing the return value of `indexOf` and making your decision based on that.

Comment: Other than readability, is there anything else wrong with using (!) directly with indexOf? A case where value isn't found, will always return -1(truthy), which makes final result false. So why use the longer syntax of .indexOf('string') > -1

Comment: The longer syntax speaks to what you are actually doing (i.e. looking for the index of an element in an array). Valid indexes range from 0 to length - 1. Hence it is more intuitive rather than coercing the value to a boolean. Coercing and testing not very useful anyway, because other than `0`, every other index is "truthy", whereas the only value that you really care about is `-1` which *also* happens to be truthy. So you would have to do something like `arr.indexOf(i) && arr.indexOf(i) > -1` to see if you have a valid index. So why not just do `arr.indexOf(i) > -1` anyway?

Comment: Just a minor edit to the comment above. The full expression would be `(arr.indexOf(i) && arr.indexOf(i) !== -1) || !arr.indexOf(i)`, which is more complicated than just checking `arr.indexOf(i) !== -1`.

Comment: indexOf returning truthy when it can't find is not following principle of least astonishment

Answer (score 0):

To check what is certain variables conversion to boolean, the best trick is to use boolean operator to it. For example `!` (negation) is boolean operator that gives you negative (`true` for `false` and vice versa) of that value.

And this knowledge is in Javascript (and also PHP and Python) used like this:

```
var booleanValue = !!someVariable;
```

That is in your case:

```
!!(-1) //returns true
```

So yes, `-1` will convert to true by implicit javascript conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, only "0" is false. When make a call with a preceeding "!", javascript will cast everything to boolean. 
Another interesting fact:

```
console.log(!!!a);    // false
console.log(!!!b);    // true
```

Thereby casting your "a" to a boolean with !! and getting the inverse value

Answer (score 0):

`-1` is a `trule`-like value. The only `false`-like value between numbers in JavaScript is `0`. Other `false`-like values are `''`, `NaN`, `undefined`... I hope i didn't miss anything.

When using indexOf all you need to do is

```
if (someString.indexOf('value') >= -1) {
    //code if someString contains 'value'
}
```