# Why does the %remainder operator returns the same results in this Even or Odd Checker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

Why does this code "(number % 2)" work the same as this code "(number % 2 == 1)" even tho i didn't specify how much the remainder of the division should be?

```js
var number = parseInt(prompt("even or odd number checker"));
if (number % 2) {
  alert("odd");
} else {
  alert("even");
}

var number = parseInt(prompt("even or odd number checker"));
if (number % 2 == 1) {
  alert("odd");
} else {
  alert("even");
}
```

Comment: Because any integer modulo 2 is equal to 0 or 1, the result of a modulo operation can't be `>=` to the modulo itself

Comment: Anything but `0` is truthy (except sheNaNagins).

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966139/safest-way-to-guard-against-missing-and-undefined-parameters/69966195#69966195

You're evaluating truthiness in your conditional which is why it continues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In javascript is -1 true or false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726070/in-javascript-is-1-true-or-false) particularly the quote about the spec saying: "All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN)"